# show touch using code (including Marshmallow and above)

Tags: android, touch

I searched in stackoverflow and some suggested the following:

```
 Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
            "show_touches", 1);
```

1. The problem is, this does not work with Android M and above with the following error

   > IllegalStateException: You cannot change private secure settings.
2. Some suggested to use **targetSdkVersion 22 and below** to use the code above, but our app need newer feature above 22

Is there any way we can implement show touch?

*p/s: I also tried Window Manager to put an overlay on top of the screen. Unfortunately, it only allows touch event while blocking all the views behind the overlay*

Comment: `blocking all the views behind the overlay` looks like you are `return true` in your ontouch. This way it will consume the touch event. If you return false, it should apss it to the bottom

Comment: there is no `"show_touches"` in [Settings.System](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) constants

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes. I have returned false at onTouchEvent in my view (which added into the Window Manager)

Comment: @pskink, really? But if i use targetSdkVersion 22, it works~

Comment: so what do you expect if you use those magic strings (and not public API constants)?

Comment: @pskink agree that it has no public API constant. Do you have any suggestion on alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` to your manifest?

From android version `M` which requires a runtime permissions. Try to add runtime permission `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` and check.

Comment: Hi @Archana, yes added in Android manifest. Also tried requesting runtime permission and start activity with new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS). That's where I got "You cannot change private secure settings." error